# Multiplicar valores de un diccionario anidado por otro diccionario en base a las claves. Python

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, bucles, diccionarios

estoy intentando crear el siguiente diccionario:

```
{'doc01': {'A': 1,'B': 30,'N': 40, ...},
 'doc02': {'B':30, 'N':40,...},
 'doc03': {...},
 ...
 }
```

La información inicial que tengo es un diccionario anidado y otro diccionario con keys compartidas.

Mi intención es multiplicar los valores del diccionario anidado por los valores del diccionario 2, en función de las claves.

Diccionario 1:

```
{'doc01': {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'N': 1...},
 'doc02': {'B': 3,'C': 10,'Ñ': 3,...},
 'doc03': {'N': 1,'Ñ': 3},
 ...}
```

Diccionario 2:

```
{'A': 1,
 'B': 10,
 'C': 4,
 'D': ...}
```

Entiendo que debo iterar ambos diccionarios juntos pero no consigo obtener nada lógico.

En definitiva trato de actualizar los valores del diccionario 1, multiplicandolos por los valores del diccionario 2 en función de unas key comunes:

```
for dict2 in diccionario1.values():
  for m,n in diccionario2.items():
```

pero no logro continuar. Comentar que los diccionarios tienen longitudes distintas.

Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: El diccionario 1 y diccionario 2, no veo como general el diccionario que deseas como resultado. ya que el diccionario 2 no está contenido en él.

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa como comentas, no está contenido, trato de actualizar los valores del diccionario 1, multiplicando los valores del diccionario anidado por los valores del diccionario 2, con unas claves comunes, pero no ordenadas ni con la misma longitud

Comment: Bueno si ambos diccionarios tienen longitudes distintas habrá que iterar en el que sepamos que todas las claves se encuentran en el otro. Podrías indicar si todas las claves de `diccionario1` se encuentran en `diccionario2`??

Comment: Ademas podrías podrías proporcionar un ejemplo de salida??

Comment: @Christian odas las claves se encuentran en ambos diccionarios. En el diccionario 1 aparecen en múltiples diccionarios anidados y en el diccionario 2 únicamente una vez. 

La salida sería la mostrada al inicio de la consulta, que no es más que el diccionario 1 actualizado,  con los valores multiplicados por los valores del diccionario 2.

He tratado de simplificar la consulta y quizás la este complicando... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues no es nada difícil, solo tienes que pensar correctamente como hacerlo. Si queremos actualizar según el `diccionario2` entoncesvamos a recorrerlo, pero necesitamos tanto su key como su value, yo opté por usar `dict.keys()` ya que con la key podemos obtener el valor. Luego necesitamos recorrer el `diccionario2` pero como este contiene otros diccionarios necesitaremos comprobar si la `key` de `diccionario2` se encuentra en este, esto solo para evitar posibles errores y luego necesitamos actualizar el valor, lo cual se hace tan solo re-asignando el valor.

```py
#dict1 corresponde al diccionario 1 y dict2 al diccionario2
for key in dic2.keys():
    for dics in dic1.values():
        if key in dics.keys(): #verificamos que se encuentre
            dics[key]*=dic2[key] #asignamos el nuevo valor

print(dic1)
```

Comment: Me estaba obcecando y no verificaba que se encontrase en el otro diccionario, a pesar de saber que si se encontraba. Funciona a la perfección en el caso que quería aplicar. Muchísimas gracias.